# How do I randomly add points across geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

I was making a geometry node tree and I was wondering how I can use the point distribute an Icophere across my mesh?[image]

[image]

Comment: do you mean the *Point Distribute* node?

Comment: Yes but when I tried to use this node it just makes the entire model disappear. I added some images to help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just change the order of the nodes then it will work as expected:
Point Distribute -> Point Scale -> Point Instance

The *Random* mode distributes the points in random order. Overlapping and intersections can occur.

The *Poisson Disk* avoids overlapping and intersections. You need to adjust the *Distance Min* value to the instance object's size.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Which order do I have to do the nodes in?

Comment: The image can be enlarged by clicking it, can't it? The order is Point Distribute -> Point Scale -> Point Instance.

Comment: Thanks, I just didn't set the density high enough, I didn't realize it had to be such a high value